# calculating same thing twice getting different result

Tags: probability

When you sneeze, it's possible that some other people in the world sneezed at the same time as you.

Suppose you are given the probability distribution $P(X=k)$ for the probability that $k$ people sneezed at the same time as you for any given sneeze, for all values of $k$ in the entire world population, let's call it $L = 1000$. For the sake of argument, let's say $P(X=0) = 0, P(X=1) = 0.4, P(X=2) = 0.3 $ and for $k > 2$ we have $P(X=k) = 0$ just to make it simple.

My question is as follows:

For any given person, the probability that he will sneeze at the same time as you is $p = \sum_{a=0}^{2}\frac{a}{1000}P(X=a) = \frac{1}{1000}$, hence the probability that he won't sneeze at the same time as you is $(1-p) = \frac{999}{1000}$, this is true for any one single person.

So the probability that no one will sneeze at the same time as you, over the entire population should be $(\frac{999}{1000})^{1000}$, but this number is already given to us by $P(X=0)$ and they are not the same!

What's the mistake in the logic here?

Comment: "For any given person, the probability that he will sneeze at the same time as you is $p = \sum_{a=0}^{2}\frac{a}{1000}P(X=a) = \frac{1}{1000}$"

why would this be the case?

Comment: Also, you are assuming that the sneezes of individals are iid when you say that for the total population, the propability is $\frac{999}{1000}^{1000}$. Where is the justification for that assumption?

Comment: You sneezed. The probability I sneezed with you is dependent on how many people sneezed with you. If only 1 sneezed with you (0.4 chance) then the probability its me is $1/1000$. If 2 people sneezed with you (0.3 chance) then the probability its me is $2/1000$ and so on.

Comment: and yes that's correct I assume these are independent events.

Comment: THis is all assuming that probability of sneezing is equally distirbuted over the whole population, which I don't see as a justified assumption.

Comment: If these are independent events, then how can you even be sure that there exists a sneezing-distribution that, when applied on to 1000 individuals, yields the aggregate random variable $X$ that you describe?

Comment: I agree it's not realistic, but for the sake of the thought experiment, go with me here.

Comment: No, I it's not that it's unrealistic. It's *impossible*. You cannot have $1000$ random variables that are both iid and that yield the aggregate variable $X$ with the required property. It's not about being realistic or not, it's about it being possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming the probability that a person sneezes is independently and identically distributed over the entire population.

However, if that is true, the $P(X=k)=0$ for $k>2$ is not possible. It would imply that $P(\text{person 1 sneezed}|\text{person 2 sneezed} \land \text{person 2 sneezed}\land \text{person 3 sneezed})$ is always zero, violating the independence assumption.

In other words, if at any given time, there is a nonzero positive probability $p$ that one person sneezes, then, if all other person's sneezing is independent of that one person's sneeze, that already tells you that there is a nonzero probability $p^{1000}$ that **all** people sneezed. However, you demand that probability to be zero, which is not compatible.

Your assumptions are self-contradictory, so of course, they yield weird results.

Comment: I understand, Thank you, that's correct.

Comment: Also, $0.5+0.4+0.3>1$ so the given distribution is invalid in any case.

Comment: That's a typo, ignore it. Fixed.